# GIMP will not start, GEGL error

Tags: gimp

I get this error,

> GEGL version too old!
>
> GIMP requires GEGL version 0.4.16 or later.
>   Installed GEGL version is 0.4.14.
>
> Somehow you or your software packager managed
>   to install GIMP with an older GEGL version.
>
> Please upgrade to GEGL version 0.4.16 or later.

I've tried removing and reinstalling GIMP. I've tried removing and reinstalling GEGL. When I do, it appears it is installing 0.4.16. Same error every time. It was working just the other day. Version 2.10

I don't know what to try next.

Comment: I think it was originally installed by adding this repository, ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp. So how can I get back to a working gimp? removing the repository and installing from the software center gives me the same error.

Comment: @ticotexas can you list the steps - the exact ones, paste the command lines into your question - you used to add that PPA and install GIMP?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp`,  
`sudo apt update`,  
`sudo apt-get install gimp`

Comment: At this point, I want to remove gimp, the repository, and start over fresh. I guess I need more explicit help to do this. I've tried `sudo apt-get purge gimp`, `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp`, `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt-get install gimp`. This results in The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.10.8-z) but 2.10.12+om-1ubu19.04.1~ppa is to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.10.8-z) but 2.10.12+om-1ubu19.04.1~ppa is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had to add the repo again. Then run:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

After that gimp was able to install and start normally.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Thank You! That works.

Comment: still getting same error , tried everything you mentioned. Actually, i upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 from 19.10. Does this might be creating this issue ?

Comment: I have tried this but it did not work. When I reinstalled it, the app tried to launch in the "Activities" bar, but after a few seconds, it disappeared & the app never launched.

Answer (score 3):

When you say

> I've tried removing and reinstalling GEGL.

you’ve been updating the standalone GEGL package. What GIMP needs is the libgegl package, which is not included in ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp for some reason. I have submitted a bug report to the PPA maintainer.

Comment: It says: "I promise as long as I live this PPA will never die and the most recent packages will for ever be. ;-)"
I hope he is alive.
If not RIP Otto Kesselgulasch / Taiga Wutz (Táigður Wutzson)
https://www.facebook.com/otto06217

Answer (score 3):

I had remove gimp and gegl with

```
sudo dpkg --remove gegl
sudo dpkg --remove gimp
```

And reinstalled again to get it work.

Comment: As @xaif commented, this happened to me after upgrading to 20.04. Your solution worked for my case.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. It does not drop the whole bunch of utility files and so on. This answer worked instead: https://askubuntu.com/a/1261589/35185

Answer (score 1):

I received this error, too, & tried all the solutions to resolve it. Now, when I try to launch GIMP, I see it trying to launch in the "Activities" bar, but then it disappears & the app fails to launch. I've purged it from my system & have tried reinstalling it, but so far nothing has worked. I still cannot get the app to launch in 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can force another version of libgegl.
I dont know why, but the version 0.4.14 is showed as higher version than 0.4.16 so even when you have the 0.4.16 version it will be updated to 0.4.14.
You have to force version 0.4.16 and downgrade the 0.4.14 to 0.4.16 version.