# GEGL version too old error?

Tags: 20.04, gimp

I am getting GEGL version too old error whlie opening GIMP after updating to Ubuntu 20.04. The complete error is

```
GEGL version too old!

GIMP requires GEGL version 0.4.22 or later.
Installed GEGL version is 0.4.18.

Somehow you or your software packager managed
to install GIMP with an older GEGL version.

Please upgrade to GEGL version 0.4.22 or later.
```

But I checked my installed gegl version which is 0.4.22-3.

[image: GEGL image]

[I have done described here but it does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152945/gimp-will-not-start-gegl-error)

Please help !!!  I am not able to use GIMP.

Here is /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 19.10 _Eoan Ermine_ - Release amd64 (20191017)]/ eoan main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Comment: This is the same to me, but... It is happening only when I try to open some file clicking on it. If I open GIMP first, I don't get the message and the app works so fine. I think this is some mistake with a library related with the files manager, only. Just my guess.

Comment: Please post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @Liso Because the /etc/apt/sources.list is too big to put it here... I just write the way I got GIMP...  GIMP 2.10.18 (2020-02-03) from Universe/Graphics, through Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: Perhaps you have a not-system version of the GEGL library elsewhere - such as `/usr/local/lib`? BTW how did you install GIMP?

Comment: @steeldriver GIMP is installed with Ubuntu Studio and it is upgraded each time there is some new version. That's the reason I said it is IN the Synaptic Packages Manager.

Comment: I think I have "some" idea from where this problem is coming... There is an snap GIMP version, there is an "standard" GIMP version (included in the Synaptic Packages Manager) and there is the Otto Kesselgulasch version. I don't have any clue how to get just one of those version, only. But... I discovered that if we uninstalled the gegl library and we create a launche with this line... env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/gimp_gimp.desktop /snap/bin/gimp %U ...Everything is working so fine, here!!! (But, I suspect that only the snap version is really working, here)

Comment: BTW: I uninstalled ALL the gimp I found in my PC, and I erased all the files I found with that name "gimp" (I did it with sudo privileges). Then, I re-installed the app from the snap (Gnome Software Center) only. Now... It is running so fine!!! But... Now, there is not something related to gimp into Synaptic Packages Manager and/or with the dpkg command line. So.. As I suspected, only the snap version works so fine.

Comment: @Juan snap versus deb was exactly why I asked about the installation method... let's see if your observation helps the OP as well

Comment: @steeldriver ```which gegl```  showing  ```/usr/bin``` location of gegl. And, I installed GIMP using ubuntu softwares app.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu Mate 20.04.

Resolved it as follows.  The otto-kesselgulasch [repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Eotto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) is depreciated and is no longer maintained. It needs to be [replaced](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/gimp/+index).

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/gimp
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If that doesn't work you may need to re-install GIMP

```
sudo apt install gimp gimp-gmic
```

This worked for me.

You may also need to do

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

and

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

for a number of cycles until all the dependencies are satisfied and unused dependencies removed.

Trying to install GEGL didn't help for me.  I removed / purged GIMP (and GEGL 0.4.22 - it was installed correctly!) as above a number of times without result.  However, doing this routine from the start worked first-time on my second machine!

Thanks to [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/ppa-install-gimp-2-10-20-ubuntu-20-04/) for hosting the repository.

Comment: I do not see any deprecation clues at the [*otto-kesselgulasch* PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp?field.series_filter=focal).

Comment: Apologies, probably a better word is inactive.  On the [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) he has written _"for personal reasons my PPA activities are dropped for the time being."_  The most recent version in the PPA is 2.10.14 and not 2.10.20.

Comment: Thanks...that worked for me.  I think a lot of Otto refuges are having these same issues...

Comment: If after that you've got: `gimp: symbol lookup error: gimp: undefined symbol: gegl_buffer_share_storage`, purge libgegl and reinstall gimp as this answer states: https://askubuntu.com/a/1287159/377874

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked for me! :)

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. You can solve it by removing gimp with

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove gimp
```

This also removes the leftover dependencies of the gimp packages, and hence all the versions of libgegl and older dependencies.

and  then reinstall gimp by

```
sudo apt install gimp
```

This will install the latest versions of the required dependencies for gimp.

Comment: This answer is underrated. A *complete* reinstall also includes
`Setting up libgegl-common (0.4.22-3) ...`
`Setting up libgegl-0.4-0:amd64 (0.4.22-3) ...`

Comment: I have done all of this but the app will start to launch and then it will stop. Still can't get the app to launch. I've tried purging it but when I reinstall it, it still will not launch.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Works for me too on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt purge gimp
sudo apt purge libgegl-0.4-0
sudo apt install gimp
```

worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please add some details so people know what you are doing and why you are doing it.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: I tried all the above answers. This is the only/first one that worked for me on "old" gimp @Ubuntu 18->20

Comment: Agree with @SYK.  The dist-upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 left GIMP complaining about GEGL, and attempts to upgrade 'libgegl-0.4-0' met Ubuntu's response that it was already the latest.  (I should add that I don't know if all my GIMP customizations are there--after all, I did a 'purge'.  YOU might want to try a 'remove' first.)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, solved by removing Otto PPA:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge -y
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
```

It will tell you that some packages need a downgrade, accept et voila'

(I was coming from 19.10 upgraded to 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded from Kubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.
For me, none of the above solutions worked, couldn't start gimp because of gegl error.

I searched for gegl version still installed:

```
$ sudo apt list | grep gegl

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gegl/focal,now 0.4.22-3 amd64  [installiert]
gir1.2-gegl-0.4/focal 0.4.22-3 amd64
libgegl-0.4-0/now 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu18.04.18~ppa amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libgegl-common/now 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu18.04.18~ppa all  [Installiert,lokal]
libgegl-dev/focal 0.4.22-3 amd64
libgegl-doc/focal,focal 0.4.22-3 all
```

The I removed the old gegl version:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libgegl-0.4-0
```

After that, gimp starts again :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can just try:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install gegl
```

Answer (score -1):

Con esto me ha funcionado a mi.

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp

sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Saludos,

Comment: English please!